# How to return 2 output from a list

Tags: python-3.x

Probably a very stupid Q!  Too much office has damaged my brain today.

I am stuck at solving a basic problem from a site.

I have a function that has 3 values in tuple (name, age, gender). I have worked on getting just age & gender in a list & then iterating there to get average if the gender matches M or F and No match if anything apart from it.

Now I am stuck in the problem in BOLD  in the code where I am unable to return either one of the output i.e. if  gender = "m' or 'f' it works properly, but if it uses avergae_age(members,Z), it doesnt return ' No matches found' instead error, which is obvious.

1. How do I make this code better?

b) How do I just get the output if anything apart form M/F is input without changing my existing code pls ?

Thanks in advance

```
def average_age(members,gender):
lst=[]
for x in zip(members):
     lst.append(x[0][1])
     lst.append(x[0][2])


lst_tuple = [x for x in zip(*[iter(lst)]*2)]

#return lst_tuple

**lst1=[]
for z in lst_tuple:
    if z[1]!=gender:
        lst1=[]
return ("No matches found.")

for z in lst_tuple:
    if z[1]==gender:
        lst1.append(z[0])
return (sum(lst1)/len(lst1))**
```

Comment: Maybe you can provide some sample inputs and outputs first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For input data:

```
members = [("Maria", 20, "F"), ("Dan", 21, "M"), ("Ana", 30, "F"), ("Max", 40, "M")]
```

You can compute average age like this:

```
def average_age(members: list, gender: str):

    # Collect ages for the given gender
    ages = [member[1] for member in members if member[2] == gender]

    try:
        return sum(ages) / len(ages)

    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print("Unable to compute average age")
```